# Array formulas and Logic, checking against multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I'm currently just troubleshooting a report spreadsheet I've written. The logic I had written isn't working, so I thought I'd see if I could ask for some help here.

Essentially, I have a list of contracts, a list of products, a list of end and start dates, and various other pieces of information. I need to know if a product of a renewal using this information.

Example Data:

```
Product   Company Number    Start of Contract        End of contract     Contract ID     Include in this month's report
Fax            1234             10.09.2013              10.09.2014           1                      No
Fax            1234             10.09.2014              10.09.2015           2                      No     
Box            5678             11.01.2014              30.04.2015           3                      No
Box            5678             01.05.2015              11.01.2016           4                     Yes
Fax            5678             01.05.2015              01.05.2016           5                     Yes
Cup            9876             03.05.2015              03.05.2016           6                     Yes
```

What I want to do is work out using this data whether the file is new to product, new to business, or renewal of an existing file.

The logic behind whether the contract should be included in this month's report is simple - simply check if `Start date` is the month requested elsewhere in the report.

In the example given above,

- Contract ID's 1,3 and 6 are new to business
- ID's 2 and 4 are Renewals
- Id 5 is new to product, with existing business with the company

I've worked out the basic way of working out for this month if there is a new to product file, because the company number won't be unique, but the product will. I'd like to make this better though, because if this done as is, it will return as "False" for the first occurrence of where the product has subsequently been renewed.

What I need to do is find a way of checking if there is a previous contract with us that was with the product listed, contracts with completely new clients, and contracts where there IS a previous contract with us that WASN'T with the same product. In essence, as below, but automatically calculated from the above table.

Results:

```
Contract ID     Renewal?        New to Product?         New to Business?
    1              No                  No                     Yes
    2             Yes                  No                     No
    3              No                  No                     Yes
    4             Yes                  No                     No
    5              No                 Yes                     No
    6              No                  No                     Yes
```

I've got a few helper columns so far, like "ended in last 12 months", and "number of agreements". but I keep getting turned around when it comes to the logic for the three final results!

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want your columns to look like:

[image]

Here are the formulas used:

- G2 is `=IF(AND(B2=B1,A2=A1),"Yes","No")`
- H2 is `=IF(AND(B1=B2,A2<>A1),"Yes","No")`
- I2 is `=IF(B2<>B1,"Yes","No")`

Comment: Answered over on Stack Overflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530423/use-an-array-formula-to-check-if-a-similar-contract-ended-in-the-last-12-months

Comment: @Miller86, Glad that you got an answer that works for you.